# How to unbend some part of mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]

I want to unbend some parts of the mesh. Below i have a Plastic model below the plastic model the is leather which has been bend on the pillow. The Plastic model and the leather are been pasted, so the pasted part will not bend on the pillow. (Note i have not attach or join plastic and leather mesh, due to distorted mesh going in the blend file attach). I tried to make verts group and assign, but for me it's not working, Any suggestions or help to fix the issue? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just select those vertices and press `S`,`Z`,`0,`,`Enter`

Comment: unbend == flatten? Think from that perspective.